# HTML text is one line higher with no css styling added

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="site-rating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
       <span itemprop="name">Example.com</span>
       <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
       was rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/5 based on <a href="#reviews" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="reviewCount">178</span> reviews</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

This code displays the following:

[image]

I've tried `white-space:nowrap` but it doesn't work.

How to move Example.com text in the same line with the other text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/na80x3en/)**

```
.site-rating span,.site-rating div{
    display:inline;
}
```

`white-space` wont work in your case. If you use `display inline to span` and div which is inside `site-rating`, you can align both in same line.

Answer (score 1):

allcote 1 id to your inner div

and the following style

```css
#innerDiv {
  display:inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="site-rating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
       <span itemprop="name">Example.com</span>
       <div id="innerDiv" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
       was rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/5 based on <a href="#reviews" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="reviewCount">178</span> reviews</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the Example.com span inside the same div as all other span elements are, like this:

```
<div class="site-rating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
       <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
       <span itemprop="name">Example.com</span>
       was rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/5 based on <a href="#reviews" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="reviewCount">178</span> reviews</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

In output you will then see:

Example.com
           was rated 4/5 based on 178 reviews